# Associating Contacts from a Parent Account with a Child Account to express permissions?

Tags: custom-field

I'm new to Salesforce and am trying to figure out if what I think I should be able to do is feasible. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Consider the following example hierarchy:

```
Account "Acme Nursery Rhymes" (type: Organization) with contacts "Jack" and "Jill"
- Child Account "The Hill" (type: Location)
```

What I want to be able to do at the Location account level is choose Contacts from the Parent to signify permissions. For example in this case, let's say I want to choose that Jack has access to The Hill, but Jill doesn't.

In my mind I'm imagining some sort of control that would show up on "Location" account types which would present a list of the Contacts in the parent and you'd be able to check each Contact that had access to the Location.

Here's a visual representation of what I'm hoping to do:

[image: Visual Description]

Any pointers in the right direction are appreciated. Ultimately I'll be querying these relationships for use in another solution. I've got the SOQL basics down but am chasing my tail trying to figure out how to build and express this relationship.

Comment: You cannot do this Natively but you can most certainly do it via apex/custom Visualforce - is that a direction you would be willing to go? The other downside is even if they were giving sharing rights to the children accounts, you would not be able to specify WHY, the only option is Manual Sharing which would bake it difficult to manage the sharing based on different reason for the sharing being given.

Comment: Thank you for your insight Eric! I will check out the APEX/Visualforce route to see what I can come up with. One thing to note is when I'm talking about sharing or permissions, I'm not actually referring to literal Salesforce permissions, I simply want to, for example, query for a Location account and somehow determine that Jack and Jill (from the parent account) are logically linked in some fashion. I could very well be confusing the issue by not being very familiar with Salesforce sharing / permission concepts... but ultimately Jack and Jill aren't actually logging into Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

This won't totally answer your question, but it's more than I can put in comments, thus the reason I'm posting it as an answer. In your question, you mention:

> a list of the Contacts in the parent and you'd be able to check each Contact that had access to the Location.

In Salesforce, Contacts are children of Account, meaning they're in a Master-Detail relationship with Account. The Contact is a child of Account. Your sharing model for Account and for Contacts is what's important to know. In essence, who has access to and/or owns the Account, will generally determine who has access to and can see the related Contacts. It's not about what Contact can "see" different Accounts, but instead it's best described as being viewed from the opposite perspective as in from Account -> Contact.

If you'll tell us what your current sharing model is for Account and for Contact, we can much better advise you on how to achieve what you desire.

Comment: This is very good to know and I appreciate the help! However I think my lack of familiarity with Salesforce might be causing me to word my question in a misleading fashion. Ultimately I just want to define contacts under the main account and in each (child) Location account be able to "mark" contacts from the main account a logical way that I can query from another app through the API.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not nearly as simple as you're asking it to be. The sharing model will control whether child accounts will have any kind of read-only or read-write access to the contacts related to the parent or their sibling accounts. Users with appropriate permissions in the parent accounts will have no problems seeing contacts related to child accounts, thus the need for information on the Org Wide Defaults and any other sharing info you have on the Account and Contact Objects.